# Is there a way to page through text one occurance of a string at the time?

Tags: command-line, more

`more is a filter for paging through text one screenful at a time` is said in [man pages for `more`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/more.1.html). Is there a way to **page through text**, but instead of getting to the next page, the procedure will get to the **next occurance of a string** supplied via a parameter? The first time it will display the first occurance of the string (at the top of the screen) let's say, `STRING1`. The next time I press the SPACE bar, the `crt` display will show the line of the next occurance of string `STRING1`, etc.

Comment: To summarize, you're trying to have a sort of string search loop with a user waiting in each loop, done in bash?

Comment: @steeldriver: It's not important to me which key will bring the display to the next occurance. The `n` key is as good to me as the `SPACE`bar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read `man more`.

It describes the command line option:

```
+/string
     The string to be searched in each file before starting to display it.
```

And it also describes the '/' and 'n' interactive commands:

```
/pattern  Search for kth occurrence of regular expression.  Defaults to 1.

n         Search for kth occurrence of last regular expression.  Defaults to 1.
```

Comment: Beautifull! That's exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!!